# My Router is timing out

Tags: wireless-router

My router is timing out from time to time. I can see it when I ping its address/gateway and sometimes huge latency up to 3k ms and I cant access the router page.  I thought my old router is dying and then I bought a new one(Huawei WS329) but still the same behavior specially at night when all devices are connected..

My router is supporting around 25 smart phones mostly just for browsing facebook/emails/sometimes YouTube.

Why the router itself is timing out? Do you think my home router can't handle the load?

Comment: It sounds like you are experiencing wireless interference. You should investigate the airwaves, and you may need to make adjustments based on the results.

Comment: do you think the 25 phones meters away from the router is causing the problem?

Comment: Probably not, but you don't own the airwaves, and there are all sorts of reasons for interference which could cause your problem. Most of the time, the interference is out of your control, and you just need to adapt.

Comment: Sorry but can you be more specific about that airwaves? I live 25 km away from the city and there is only 1 wifi signal from a  neighbor I  know at channel 11 and I'm on different channel.. Can you site more specific example about that airwaves that can possibly affect my home network.. tnx

Comment: Wi-Fi is not the only thing which uses the unlicensed frequencies. The wireless phone carriers are experimenting with, and rolling out, LTE/U which uses the same frequencies, also Bluetooth, some cordless phones, remote controls, etc. The whole point of the unlicensed frequencies is that they are not reserved for anything, and people can use them and experiment with them as they wish. You could try using a different channel, or you can get a tool, software, or hire an expert to check what is really going on in the wireless spectrum. You could also log the Internet connection for overuse.

Comment: Is it just one device timing out or all of them?

Comment: @ekaj all devices connected in the router

Comment: it appears the router is choked

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines on the [FAQ for the router](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/676177/Huawei-Ws329.html?page=50#manual), I get the distinct impression this router is a low end router, and is not designed to - and probably not capable of - handling the number of devices you are using.

The first thing to do is to ensure the DHCP address range set up on the router is large enough for all your devices.  If it is, go out and get a prosumer router -or a router you can turn into a prosumer router by reflashing with dd-wrt.

Comment: I believe so.. I just  purchased this  - [Ubiquiti UAP](http://www.lazada.com.ph/ubiquiti-unifi-long-range-access-point-white-828442.html) and let see if it can do better..